# Unity Character Controller script + PlayerCam locked my camera rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and C#,
I created (copied) a PlayerCam script so I could look with my mouse

```
public class PlayerCam : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Range(0, 1000)] public int Sens;

    float xRotation;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Sens * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Sens * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90, 90);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, transform.position.y, 0);

        transform.parent.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }
}
```

I then created (copied) a movement + rotation script:

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    public float jumpForce = 5f;
    public Vector3 _direction;

    private CharacterController characterController;

    void Start() 
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }
    void Update()
    {

        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical);
        characterController.Move(movement * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

        var targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(_direction.x, _direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f);
    }
}
```

Now when I start my game I am stuck looking at Z forward
[Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWiWU.png)

As I am new, any suggestions in learning and understanding these types of mechanics would be appreciated or even some suggestions for throwaway code i could play around with to get a better understanding of whats happening.

I was expecting to be able to look at a direction and have my "forward" change that direction, so that i could walk where i am looking, but instead even with the movement script and mouse look script i can only walk on z and x.

Originally i thought this could be solved by adding some kind of rotation script, but now that i think about it, i realize im missing something, there is no connection between where i am looking and how i am rotated, but i havent learned enough to know how to correct this yet.

I checked the similar questions, and i still feel the need to ask.

Comment: [Please add your code here instead of images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/17985195)

Answer (score 1):

well your camera is locked because of this part of your PlayerCam script:

```
float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Sens * Time.deltaTime;
float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Sens * Time.deltaTime;

xRotation -= mouseY;
xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90, 90);

transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, transform.position.y, 0);
```

try something like this:

```
float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Sens * Time.deltaTime;
float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Sens * Time.deltaTime;

yRotation += mouseY;
yRotation = Mathf.Clamp(yRotation, -90, 90);
transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, yRotation, 0);
```

I don't know exactly what you are trying to make but I guess you dont want your left and right movement of your mouse (Y-axis) to rotate your camera around your x-axis right? And with `float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")...` you are doing the opposite instead use `Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")`.

Also, you are using `transform.localRotation` but `eulerAngles` are world rotation. You could use `transform.localEulerAngles` but I'd rather just use eulerAngles tbh.

And your camera is locked because of this line `transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, transform.position.y, 0);` with this you rotate around the X-axis but your Y-axis rotation is locked by your Y-position instead use `transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3 (0, yRotation, 0);`.

Again, I don't know exactly what you are trying to make but I hope this helps you somehow. If you have any more questions feel free to ask.